# Error en Bot Pancakeswap

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Según tengo entendido mi script está bien, pero por alguna razón sale el siguiente error al correrlo en la terminal

> Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Creo que tengo todo bien.

**Este es el código**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const numeral = require('numeral');
const _ = require('lodash');
const axios = require('axios');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5007;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Using port: ${ PORT }`));

const web3 = new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, process.env.RPC_URL));

const PANCAKESWAP_FACTORY_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
const PANCAKESWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73';
const pancakeswapFactoryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(PANCAKESWAP_FACTORY_ABI, PANCAKESWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS);

const BUSD_COIN = '0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56';

const PAIR_ADDRESS0 = await pancakeswapFactoryContract.methods.getPair('0x4e6415a5727ea08aae4580057187923aec331227', WBNB_COIN).call().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err...\n'+err);
  });
```